# Wiring a switch in horn line for on/off operation

Tags: wiring, alarm, horn

I have an '06 Ford Escape with a faulty door jamb (somewhere out of 4) that causes the alarm to go off at inopportune times, especially in the summer.  I've learned it's an expensive and time consuming/trial-and-error fix.  I'd like to wire a switch in the horn line and place it somewhere on my dash, so I can turn the horn off when I get out of the car and turn it on while driving so I can use my horn. (I'm not concerned about the lights flashing when the alarm goes off--just the noise from the horn)(right now, the fuse to the horn is removed)  I would guess that it's a relatively easy "fix", but I know nothing about car electronics or voltage dangers or wiring in general.  I don't know what gauge wire to get, what kind of switch to buy, (single pole, I think) Is it just as simple as cutting one of the wires from the horn and inserting the switch which would allow the opening and closing of the circuit?  I'm assuming there are two wires coming from the horn?  Thanks for reading and for any assistance that is offered.

Comment: why not just turn the alarm off?

Comment: @agentp Perhaps some alarms are activated automatically when locking the doors - some cars have a single lock then a double lock as well.

Answer (score 2):

Some horns have one wire (supply) and the earth is completed by the fixing, others have two connections (supply and earth).

All you need is to put a single pole switch capable of 6 amps or so between the supply wire and the terminal on the horn.

I suggest you do this at the horn terminal - you can extend the cable pair (also capable of 6 amps even 10 if it a long way betweeh horn and cabin) back into the cabin if you wish.

The reason I suggest you do this at the horn is some may suggest that you can cut the wire at the horn switch end but the alarm feed may be anywhere between the horn switch and the horn so it would still sound.